# How to retrieve a value from an object by passing a variable as a key

Tags: arrays, json, object, coffeescript, key

I have the following array of objects

```
position = [
    {exchange: 'KRAKEN', USD: 1800, EUR: 800, GBP: 800, BTC: 800},
    {exchange: 'BTCE', USD: 800, EUR: 800, GBP: 800, BTC: 800},
    {exchange: 'BITSTAMP', USD: 600, EUR: 800, GBP: 800, BTC: 800},
    {exchange: 'MYWALLET', USD: 1300, EUR: 800, GBP: 800, BTC: 800}
]
```

I also have 2 variables:
myExchange and myCurr

I'm attempting to extract the relevant currency value from the array.
i.e. if myExchange = 'KRAKEN' and myCurr = USD,then I need to fetch the result as = 1800

I'm using the following code in coffeescript (and underscore ._ as library) but it is returning as 'undefined'

```
    objBuy = _.find(position, (objBuy) ->
      objBuy.exchange is buyExchange
    )

    objBuyCurr = _.find(objBuy, (objBuyCurr) ->
      objBuy._key is buyCurr
    )
```

Eventually what I'm aiming for is to pass the object property/keys as variables dynamically. i.e.:
value = position.myExchange.myCurr (and NOT position.KRAKEN.USD)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to form your data not using an array, but with a hash table (an object in JavaScript terms) which uses `exchange` values as keys:

```
position = {
    'KRAKEN': { USD: 1800, EUR: 800, GBP: 800, BTC: 800},
    'BTCE': { USD: 800, EUR: 800, GBP: 800, BTC: 800},
    'BITSTAMP': { USD: 600, EUR: 800, GBP: 800, BTC: 800},
    'MYWALLET': { USD: 1300, EUR: 800, GBP: 800, BTC: 800}
};
```

And then extract the required field with:

```
position['KRAKEN'].USD
```

or

```
position.KRAKEN.USD
```

In you have the name of field in a variable, for example:

```
var myExchange = "KRAKEN";
var myCurr = "USD";
```

then remember that you can access any field of an object as if it was an index of an array:

```
position[myExchange][myCurr];
```

Comment: Thanks Suseika. What I need however is to be able to say:                            position.myExchange.myCurr.   i.e. us the variables dynamically. Is that possible at all ?